# Prevent window on scroll function occurring on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that runs on window scroll, I only want it to work however on screensizes of 768 and above. This is working fine if i loaded it on mobile size, but if the initial page load is on a widescreen of 768px + and then i shrink the viewport down it doesn't prevent the function?

```
(function($) {

    var s,
    clippy = {
    settings: {
      heading: $('.js-clippy'),
    },
    init: function() {
      s = this.settings;
      this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            $(window).on("load resize scroll", $.proxy(this.getClippy, this));
        }
    },

    getClippy: function(){
      s.heading.each(function() {
        var layerOffset = $(this).closest('a').offset(),
          containerOffset = layerOffset.top - $(window).scrollTop(),
          clippy = containerOffset - $(this).css("top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') - $(this).css("margin-top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        $(this).css('clip', 'rect('+ clippy +'px, auto, auto, auto)');
      });
    },
    };
    clippy.init();

  })(jQuery);
```

I've tried adding a conditional statement to my binded event with no luck...

```
bindEvents: function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            $(window).on("load resize scroll", $.proxy(this.getClippy, this)); 
        }
});
```

to the event only it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Try to add `&& $(window).outerWidth() > 768`, window's width seems to be < than 768.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider checking the width inside the `getClippy` function. That will work if you load the page with a large viewport and shrink it and vice versa.

```
    (function($) {

    var s,
    clippy = {
    settings: {
      heading: $('.js-clippy'),
    },
    init: function() {
      s = this.settings;
      this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function(){
        $(window).on("load resize scroll", $.proxy(this.getClippy, this));
    },

    getClippy: function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            s.heading.each(function() {
                var layerOffset = $(this).closest('a').offset(),
                containerOffset = layerOffset.top - $(window).scrollTop(),
                clippy = containerOffset - $(this).css("top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') - $(this).css("margin-top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
                $(this).css('clip', 'rect('+ clippy +'px, auto, auto, auto)');
            });
        }
    },
    };
    clippy.init();

  })(jQuery);
```